# Better way to echo a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Ive got a multi dimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fernando Alonso
            [time1] => 3.25
            [time2] => 3.25
            [time3] => 3.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jenson Button
            [time1] => 34
            [time2] => 34
            [time3] => 41
        )
)
```

i want to echo the data out into a table, which at the moment im doing using ($result is the array)

```
foreach ($result as $result) {
    echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($result as $driver) {
        echo "<td>$driver</td>";
      }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
```

this seems a little unnecessary, is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Nope, that would be good(ish) code (the _ish_ is because you might want to use `htmlspecialchars`). You could however make it a function if you plan to use it more then once.

Comment: Why is it `unnecessary`?  What *exactly* are you trying to do?  Is this just for debugging?

Comment: Lots of people here, me inclusive, are reading this question a bit too fast apparantly.  No vardumps, no printr's , a table boys & girls

Comment: Drupal has a theme_table function that you might want to see and adapt if possible: http://is.gd/NKlxzB

Comment: @Wrikken why would you use htmspecialchars, ive only used it in the past when collecting data from forms ?

Comment: @sam because any data could (and, eventually will) contain characters that will mess up your HTML unless properly escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to do this?

```
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time 1</th>
            <th>Time 2</th>
            <th>Time 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['time1'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['time2'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['time3'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

The "better" way to do something like this would be to write one reusable function to draw your specific table structure.

There isn't (and IMO shouldn't be) a specific function to traverse multi-dimensional arrays. The reason for this is that there could theoretically be an endless number of nested structures which would lead to unpredictable results.

The language gives you enough tools to be able to traverse any multi-dimensional array you provide as long as you back it up with the correct code structure.

---

In your example, this would be a perfectly fine way to traverse your 2 dimensional array. The only thing I would change is to not use the same name for the array and the element in the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($result as $result) {} // WRONG
```

Rather use different variables:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {} // RIGHT
```

Comment: `foreach ($result as $row) {} // RIGHT` ;p

Comment: @ste - It's `array_walk_recursive()`. But yea.. That exists (I guess) :P For the sake of assembling tables, this might get complicated because you'd need to create new rows, lots of ugly if statements would make the code much harder to read and maintain...

Comment: IMO - a nested `foreach` loop wrapped in a nice reusable clean form would be the best way to handle drawing and assembling table structures.

Comment: @Lix Oops, right. Personally, I’d opt for `array_map()`-ping with nested lambdas ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code I use quite often :

```
// Simple call :
echo '<pre>' . var_export($var, true) . '</pre>';

// Or as a function :
function var_str_repr($var, $as_html = true) {
    $repr = var_export($var, true);
    if ($as_html) {
        return '<pre>' . $repr . '</pre>';
    } else {
        return $repr;
    }
}
```

See the [var_export](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-export.php) documentation for more information.

Answer (score -1):

use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function of php.

```
$arr = ...;
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

This wont display in a table. I dont think there is a built in function to display array in a table. You have to write a simple function for that. The code thats provided in the question is simple and will do the task.

Comment: or simply `echo "<pre>".print_r($arr,true)."</pre>";`